# algorithm for item distribution

Tags: java, algorithm, distribution

I'm working on a parking lot system, and in my scenario I have 3 different parking lots each having a maximum capacity of 50 cars. I need an algorithm that when a car requests a spot, it will allocate a spot in a particular parking lot, taking into consideration that every parking lot has relatively the same amount of cars. I don't need code, however I'd appreciate any link or ideas to algorithms that could solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fair bit of research into car parking systems. See for example:

- http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/3688/1/modelling_the_choice_of_car_parks_secure.pdf
- http://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=itj.2009.101.113

There's probably lots more, that's just from a quick Google search.

You might take into account the distance from each car park, and the rate of filling/emptying of each car park.

Answer (score 1):

How about just taking the parking lot with currently the least utilization. That way over time all parking lots should have the same amount of cars.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain 3 variables -- the count of spaces free in each car park.  As cars leave, increase these numbers.  When a car requests a spot, allocate it to the car park with most free spaces and decrease the number.  If 2 or 3 car parks have the same number of spaces free, allocate at random. Repeat ad infinitum.

Why does it need to be more complicated than this ?